# Reset Parameter Values to original value read from Excel sheet

Tags: anylogic

I have parameters that's read its values from Excel spread sheet (Picture 1). However, I have a method that reduce the parameter values by x% (picture 2). I could reverse the calculation method in picture 2 which not going to help much.
Question:
I want to create a bottom that reset the parameters values to its original excel values. I am not sure how to create such a method? Appreciate any hints or ideas.

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is very redundant code you code put into a for-loop (select all your params, right click, then create a collection of Doubles).

Then, you can easily loop across all these again and simply divide them by `interNo`, getting you the original values.

Comment: Thanks, Benjamin, I have tried to create a collection before, but every time I run the model and check the parameter values within the collection shows zero for each parameter. Taking the fact the parameters in the main shows values.

Comment: Dividing by the introNo is what I am using now. However, if I multiply the parameter values by x amount of time i.e.  1st time 0.15 then a 2ndtime  0.75 and so on, the division won’t get the original value of the parameter read from excel. Unless I add the multiply values each time and store it in a Variable and divide the Variable no. I think have answered my self : )

Comment: yeah. Consider also storing things in a dbase table temporarily, really useful